# How to perform a "serial join" in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables: an experiment data table `x` and a category lookup table `dict`.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)

x = data.table(samp=c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,9,9,10,10), y=rnorm(19))
x

     samp    y
 #1:  1 -0.56047565
 #2:  1 -0.23017749
 #3:  2  1.55870831
 #4:  3  0.07050839
 #5:  3  0.12928774
 #6:  3  1.71506499
 #7:  4  0.46091621
 #8:  5 -1.26506123
 #9:  5 -0.68685285
#10:  5 -0.44566197
#11:  6  1.22408180
#12:  7  0.35981383
#13:  7  0.40077145
#14:  7  0.11068272
#15:  8 -0.55584113
#16:  9  1.78691314
#17:  9  0.49785048
#18: 10 -1.96661716
#19: 10  0.70135590

dict = data.table(samp=c(1:5, 4:8, 7:10), cat=c(rep(1,length(1:5)), rep(2,length(4:8)), rep(3,length(7:10))))

dict
#     samp cat
# 1:  1   1
# 2:  2   1
# 3:  3   1
# 4:  4   1
# 5:  5   1
# 6:  4   2
# 7:  5   2
# 8:  6   2
# 9:  7   2
# 10:  8   2
# 11:  7   3
# 12:  8   3
# 13:  9   3
# 14: 10   3
```

For each `samp`, I need to first compute the product of all `y`'s associated with it. I then need to compute the sum of these products per each sample category specified in `dict$cat`. Note that each `samp` maps to more than one `dict$cat`.

One way of doing this is merge `x` and `dict` right away, allowing row duplication (`allow.cartesian=T`):

```
setkey(dict, samp)
setkey(x, samp)
step0 = dict[x, allow.cartesian=T]
setkey(step0, samp, cat)
step1 = step0[, list(prodY=prod(y)[1], cat=cat[1]), by=c("samp", "cat")]
resMet1 = step1[, sum(prodY), by="cat"]
```

I wonder however whether this joining step can be avoided. There are a few reasons to this - for example, if `x` is enormous, duplication will use extra memory (am I right?). Also, these summary tables with duplicated rows are quite confusing, making the analysis more error-prone.

So instead I was thinking of using samples in each `dict$cat` for a binary search in `x`. I know how to do it for a single category, so an ugly way of doing it for all of them would be with a loop:

```
setkey(x, samp)
setkey(dict,samp)

pool = vector("list") 
for(n in unique(dict$cat)){
    thisCat = x[J(dict[cat==n])]
    setkey(thisCat, samp)
    step1 = thisCat[, list(prodY=prod(y)[1], cat=cat[1]), by="samp"]
    pool[[n]] = step1[, sum(prodY), by="cat"]        
}
resMet2 = rbindlist(pool)
```

But of course such loops are to be avoided. So I'm wondering if there's any way to somehow get `data.table` to iterate over the key values inside of `J()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, I'd formulate your question as follows: *for each `dict$cat`, I'd like to get `prod(y)` corresponding to each `sample` for that `cat`, and then `sum` them all up.*

Let's construct this step by step now:

1. For each `dict$cat` - sounds like you need to group by `cat`:

   ```
   dict[, ,by=cat]
   ```

   All that's left is to fill up `j` properly.
2. you need to get `prod(y)` from `x` for each sample for *this group*:

   ```
   x[samp %in% .SD$samp, prod(y), by=samp]
   ```

   extracts those rows from `x` corresponding to *this group's* `samp` (using `.SD` which stands for *subset of data*) and computes `prod(y)` on them, grouped by `samp`. Great!
3. We still need to sum them.

   ```
   sum(x[samp %in% .SD$samp, prod(y), by=samp]$V1)
   ```
4. We've the complete `j` expression. Let's plug it all in:

   ```
   dict[, sum(x[samp %in% .SD$samp, prod(y), by=samp]$V1), by=cat]
   #    cat         V1
   # 1:   1  1.7770272
   # 2:   2  0.7578771
   # 3:   3 -1.0295633
   ```

Hope this helps.

---

**Note 1:** that there's some redundant computation of `prod(y)` here, but the upside is that we don't materialise much intermediate data. So it's memory efficient. If you've too many groups, this might get slower.. and you might want to compute `prod(y)` in another variable like so:

```
x_p = x[, .(p = prod(y)), by=samp]
```

With this, we can simplify `j` as follows:

```
dict[, x_p[samp %in% .SD$samp, sum(p)], by=cat]
```

**Note 2:** that `%in%` expression creates an auto index on the first run on `x's` `samp` column to use *binary search* based subset from then on. Therefore there need not be any worries on performance due to *vector scans*.

Comment: I didn't know that %in% was optimised this way.

Comment: See [this gist on auto indexing](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/dacb9d1cac301de8d9ff). At some point, I'll wrap this in a vignette...

Answer (score 2):

You might as well collapse `x` to the `samp` level first.

```
xprod = x[, .(py = prod(y)), by=samp]
```

**Merge**

```
res2 <- xprod[dict, on = "samp"][, sum(py), by=cat]

identical(res2, resMet2) # test passed
```

**Or subset**

If `samp` is the row number in `xprod` (as here), you can subset instead of merging:

```
res3 <- xprod[(dict$samp), sum(py), by=.(cat=dict$cat)]

identical(res3, resMet2) # test passed
```

It's very simple to relabel sample IDs so that this is true.

Comment: `foverlaps()` would be an overkill here. Like the simpler solution.